# Is it possible to print Geospatial PDFs from Geoserver?

Tags: pdf, geospatial, gdal, geoserver, mapfish

Is it possible to print vector layers created from shapefiles to a Geospatial PDF from Geoserver?  I am using Geoserver for serving my map layers and OpenLayers for my mapping API.  I currently retrieve the vector layers as a WMS and print them using the standalone MapFish print module.  I print to PDFs but they are not georeferenced.  It appears that by installing GDAL and using the community module for GDAL based WCS output a geospatial PDF can be created.  But I am not sure what to do once those are implemented to get the output as a geospatial PDF.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, GeoPDFs are a horrible format and are possibly patent encumbered/proprietary (at least when I looked last 10 years ago) so they are not supported and probably can't be supported in an open source product.

Comment: Thanks @IanTurton for your reply.  I really appreciate your reply and the information.  Do you know if a geotiff file can be created as output?

Comment: It depends on the service but generally yes, but remember a WMS only gives you a **picture** of your map not the actual data so georeferencing is not really relevant

Comment: Thanks again @IanTurton for your reply.  I am trying to create maps that are georeferenced so that I can use them in an App named Avenza Maps.  A quick test revealed that the app will not use geotiffs anyway.  Thanks again.

Comment: @IanTurton I just did another quick test accessing the geotiff file another way and it worked.  So, I guess that app will use geotiff files.  The georeferencing allows the user to use GPS to display their location on the map.

Comment: Unfortunately the term "GeoPDF" is ambiguous. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoPDF = proprietary but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geospatial_PDF is an open standard which e.g. QGIS supports.